# Who's the old man in the sky in Cromartie High School?

Tags: cromartie-high-school

In *Cromartie High School*, an old man occasionally appears in the sky:

[image: old man in clouds]

No one ever comments on this, so presumably it's only we viewers who see it.

Who is he, or what is it a reference to?

Edited to add:  I found one of the scenes on YouTube [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dGJx-bbYOsQ&t=367s).

Comment: Could you provide some episode numbers and timestamps?

Comment: @AkiTanaka I suppose I can later, but having recently binged the series, my feeling is that he appears in at least half of the episodes, always in a way similar to the above screenshot.

Comment: Does he say something? Then maybe he appears in the credits. This kind of old man in the sky is usually a deceased relative or neighbor looking down from heaven. But this anime is a nonsense comedy, so it's definitely not playing a normal script.

Comment: @Ocean No, he never speaks, or even moves, that I can recall.

Comment: @Sean Do you have a video clip of his appearance with Japanese audio? It has to be some kind of joke, but with only the screenshot I can't tell what they were going for.

Comment: @Ocean I added a link to a YouTube video in which I was able to find one of the scenes where the old man appears.

Comment: Based on the video that old man is one of the weird characters that happen to appear around the school. It's most likely a reference to other anime that show deceased characters in the sky like that. There might even be a specific character this is referencing, but I can't think of any that looks like that.

Comment: @Ocean With no better alternative explanations available, I'll accept your answer if you provide an official one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A character in the sky that appears to be half transparent and isn't visible to other characters usually indicates someone recently deceased that has a relationship to someone that is still alive. The implication is that this character is now watching from heaven.

*Sakigake!! Cromartie Koukou* is a gag anime that has many weird characters appear that everyone thinks of as totally normal. The video provided has two characters talking about how all the schools are normal while being oblivious to the fact that their school is not. To have this joke work all the weird characters appear in the background being noticed and accepted as normal.

The old man in the sky appears as one of the weird characters in this part of the anime.

I'm guessing that he appeared earlier with the joke being that he is completely unrelated to anyone.